# Display MySQL user data in PHP generated table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to make an absence system in PHP and MySQL. Each absence has a leave type. I want to display this type (for example sick) in a generated HTML table. The first field on the left side is displaying the names of the users and the others are 31 fields(like a month).

I could enter the type in the tables, however I don't know how to display them only in the right table. For Example "Max" has the PK 0 and the absence with the type "Emergency" and "ASDF" the PK 2 and "Compensation", but the types are in both tables.

```
Array ( 
 [0] => 
   Array ( [start] => 0 [end] => 27 [type_FK] => Compensation [employee_FK] => 0 ) 
 [1] => 
   Array ( [start] => 1 [end] => 3 [type_FK] => Emergency [employee_FK] => 2 ) 
)
```

How can I only display the leave types form correct user in that table?

```
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
            <title>Absence System</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <?php
                    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
                    if (!$con) {
                        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                    mysql_select_db("absence_system", $con);

                    $result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM employee");
                    $row    = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                    $count_user = $row[0];


                    $result2 = mysql_query("select start, end, type_FK, employee_FK FROM absences");
                    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                        $array_absences[] = $row2;
                    }


                    $count_absences = count($array_absences);


                    $result = mysql_query("select name FROM employee");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $array_user[] = $row;
                    }





                    $result = mysql_query("select surename FROM employee");
                    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $new_array2[] = $row2;
                    }



                    for ($i = 0; $i < $count_absences; $i++) {
                        $array_absences[$i]['start'] = substr($array_absences[$i]['start'], -2);
                        $array_absences[$i]['end']   = substr($array_absences[$i]['end'], -2);

                        $array_absences[$i]['start'] = ereg_replace("^0", "", $array_absences[$i]['start']);
                        $array_absences[$i]['end']   = ereg_replace("^0", "", $array_absences[$i]['end']);

                        $array_absences[$i]['start'] = $array_absences[$i]['start'] - 1;

                        echo $array_absences[$i]['start'], "<br>";
                    }

                    print_r($array_absences);

                    echo "<table border='1'><br />";

                    echo "<tr>";
                    for ($i = 0; $i < 32; $i++) {
                        if ($i == 0) {
                            echo "<td>", "Name", "</td>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<td>", $i, "</td>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</table>";



                    for ($row = 0; $row < $count_user; $row++) {

                        echo "<table border='1'><br />";
                        echo "<tr>";
                        //Tabelle mit 31 Tagen generieren
                        for ($col = 0; $col < 32; $col++) {
                            $true = 0;
                            if ($col == 0) {
                                //Name in die ersten Felder schreiben
                                echo "<td>", $array_user[$col]['name'], " ", $new_array2[$col]['surename'], "</td>";
                            }



                            for ($i = 0; $i < $count_absences; $i++) {
                                if ($col == $array_absences[$i]['start']) {
                                    echo "<td>", $array_absences[$i]['type_FK'], "</td>";
                                    $true = 1;
                                }


                            }

                            //Normale Felder
                            if ($true == 0) {
                                echo "<td>", $col, "</td>";
                            }


                        }

                        echo "</tr>";
                    }

                    echo "</table>";
                ?>  
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>




-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.11
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Erstellungszeit: 13. Feb 2015 um 16:07
-- Server Version: 5.6.21
-- PHP-Version: 5.5.19

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Datenbank: `absence_system`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `absences`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `absences` (
  `absences_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `employee_FK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start` date NOT NULL,
  `end` date NOT NULL,
  `approved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `type_FK` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `employee`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
  `employee_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `surename` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `on_offshore_FK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location_FK` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `location`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `location` (
  `location_ID` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `on_offshore`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `on_offshore` (
  `on_offshore_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `on_off` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `type`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `type` (
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indizes der exportierten Tabellen
--

--
-- Indizes für die Tabelle `absences`
--
ALTER TABLE `absences`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`absences_ID`), ADD KEY `employee_FK` (`employee_FK`), ADD KEY `type_FK` (`type_FK`);

--
-- Indizes für die Tabelle `employee`
--
ALTER TABLE `employee`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`employee_ID`), ADD KEY `on_offshore_FK` (`on_offshore_FK`), ADD KEY `location_FK` (`location_FK`);

--
-- Indizes für die Tabelle `location`
--
ALTER TABLE `location`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`location_ID`);

--
-- Indizes für die Tabelle `on_offshore`
--
ALTER TABLE `on_offshore`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`on_offshore_ID`);

--
-- Indizes für die Tabelle `type`
--
ALTER TABLE `type`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`type`);

--
-- Constraints der exportierten Tabellen
--

--
-- Constraints der Tabelle `absences`
--
ALTER TABLE `absences`
ADD CONSTRAINT `absences_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_FK`) REFERENCES `employee` (`employee_ID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `absences_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`type_FK`) REFERENCES `type` (`type`);

--
-- Constraints der Tabelle `employee`
--
ALTER TABLE `employee`
ADD CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`on_offshore_FK`) REFERENCES `on_offshore` (`on_offshore_ID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`location_FK`) REFERENCES `location` (`location_ID`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

[image]

Comment: Since you're just starting this project it's better not to use the mysql extension, it's depricated and it has heaps of security issues. Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on what it looks like now and how you would like it to be?

Comment: I added a picture. As you can see the absences are in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

Get a list of absences for a month: `Select * from absences_table`.

Get a list of employees: `Select * from absences_table`.

Create an empty `$employees` array. Loop through the absences result and for each absence run something like:

```
  for($i=0;$i<count($absences_array);$i++){
     if(!$employees[$absences_array[$i]['employee_FK']]['dates']){
        $employees[$absences_array[$i]['employee_FK']]['dates'] = array();
     }

     $employees[$absences_array[$i]['employee_FK']]['dates'][$absences_array[$i]['employee_FK']['start']];
     for( $j=$absences_array[$j]['employee_FK']['start'];$j<$absences_array[$j]['employee_FK']['end']; $j++){
        $employees[$absences_array[$i]['employee_FK']]['dates'][$j];
     }
}
```

Now you have a dictionary of dictionary - which means something like `$employees[$employee_id]['dates'][$date]` will give you the absence type or null.

Comment: What do you mean by ['dates']? And how do I change this for the output? All I basically need is a second condition for the loop: ($col == $array_absences[$i]['start']).

Comment: I mean the 'dates' that an employee is absent - whatever you'd receive from 'Select * from absences_table'